# JOLT change string to float

Tags: jolt

Input JSON

```
{
  "sId": "1000000000000000",
  "lat": "12.934638",
  "lon": "77.693950",
  "status": "up",
  "last_change": 1503452208
}
```

My design spec:

```
[
   {
      "operation":"shift",
      "spec":{
         "Id":"Id",
         "status":"status",
         "last_change":"last_change",
         "lat":{
            "@(2,lat)":{
               "@(2,lat)":"geocoordinate.coordinates[0]"
            }
         },
         "lon":{
            "@(2,lon)":{
               "@(2,lon)":"geocoordinate.coordinates[1].",
               "#Point":"geocoordinate.type"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

as lat long is coming as string but in output i want to have it as float.
     i tried conversion function but couldn't get expected result. please help 
     me to change the lat long value into float.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "modify" as your first operation to do the type conversion first, then do you shift.

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "lat": "=toDouble",
      "lon": "=toDouble"
    }
  }
]
```

Also type conversion example here  http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-typeConversion