# convert Boolean to String for map values in nifi jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to achieve following JSON transformation using Jolt processor in NIFI
The input in json, is a map (here image is a key and image1.png is a value, and etc, with different types (String, Boolean)

input JSON

```
{
  "internal_value": "434252345",
  "settings": {
    "image": "image1.png",
    "bold": false,
    "country": false
  }
}
```

Output JSON should be

```
{
  "internal_value": "434252345",
  "settings": {
    "image": "image1.png",
    "bold": "false",
    "country": "false"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using existing Jolt operations ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pure JOLT this would be:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "settings": {
        "bold": "=toString",
        "country": "=toString"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can use this tool to prototype JOLTs:
https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Resources:

[JOLT transformation for nested JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375313/jolt-transformation-for-nested-json)

[JOLT change string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224488/jolt-change-string-to-float)