# transforming all string attributes which are boolean to true booleans

Tags: json, jolt

I thought this would be simple, perhaps it is but on my jolt learning journey i am once again struggling.

I have some json files (without a schema) which can be up to say 30Mb in size which have many thousands of string attributes at all levels of the document some of which (say 20%) which hold booleans as strings types.

I get that i can write a spec to pick out individual ones and convert them as per (post)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972556/convert-boolean-to-string-for-map-values-in-nifi-jolt]

They technique wont work for me as nesting and levels are very arbitrary and there are simply way to many of them.

so how can i apply the data type transform to any attribute which has a boolean represented as a string ?

for example input

```json
{
  "name": "Fred",
  "age": 45,
  "opentowork" : "true",
  "friends" : [
    {
      "name": "penny",
      "closefriend": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "roger",
      "farfriend": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

to desired

```json
{
  "name": "Fred",
  "age": 45,
  "opentowork" : true,
  "friends" : [
    {
      "name": "penny",
      "closefriend": false
    },
    {
      "name": "roger",
      "farfriend": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pick up attributes **opentowork**, **closefriend** and **farfriend** without explicity defining them int the spec, i also need to leave the values of the other attributes as they are (whatever level they are at).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=toBoolean` conversion just a bit separating case within the `friends` array by using `"f*"` representation from the else case `"*"` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toBoolean",
      "f*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toBoolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or some multiple **modify** specs, without explicitly defining any attribute/array/object, might be added at the number of desired levels such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toBoolean"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=toBoolean"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toBoolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes indeed this will work, but it wont work to arbitrary depth without defining the =toBoolean at each level.

Comment: yes, I already got what you need @ArthwitRail , but I don't think it's possible to find such a method to make it super-dynamic :)

Comment: Thank you, i suspected this was the case with jolt, shame really cos now i will need to go write something to do that.

Comment: Just added an alternative case @ArthwitRail